# creating mysql update string based on conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I have list of parameters and their values. I want to build mysql update string based on whether values are present or not. One way to check using if condition like below

```
if (!empty($value['p_status']) || !empty($value['quantity'])){
      $strSet = '';
      if (!empty($value['p_status'])) {
             $strSet .= "status='$value[p_status]',";
       }
      if (!empty($value['quantity'])) {
            $strSet .= "amount='$value[quantity]',";
      }
      if (!empty($value['shipping_freight'])) {
          $strSet .= "shipping_freight='$value[shipping_freight]',";
      }
   }
   $strSet = trim($strSet,',');
   db_query("update table1 set ".$strSet." where pr1=123");
```

But there can be lots of parameters. Is there is any better way to do it ?

Comment: loop it like `foreach($value as $key =>$value)` then `if (!empty($key))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your `$value` array can use the same keys as the MySQL field names that would be much simpler!
e.g. if `$value['p_status']` could simply be `$value['status']` and `$value['quantity']` could be `$value['amount']` then you could do something like this:

```
$strSet = '';
foreach ($value as $field_name=>$field_value) {
  if (!empty($strSet)) $strSet .= ',';
  if (!empty($field_value)) $strSet .= "{$field_name}='{$field_value}'";
}
db_query("update table1 set ".$strSet." where pr1=123");
```

Oh, and remember:
In PHP the `empty()` function will return `true` for NULL, an empty string and zero - so if the quantity/amount is zero your sql won't update the field!
Also, you should really escape the values you are updating to prevent sql injection.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid writing so many if conditions, simply use a loop.

```
foreach($values as $key=>$value)
{
    if(!empty($value))
        str = str." $key = '$value',";
}
$str=trim($str,',');
```